# How can I do this kind of figures/graphs in R? non-statistical figures

Tags: r, plot, graph

I wonder if someone could guide me. I would like to do this kind of figure in R, but I don't know if it's possible. I'm creating a document in R-markdown where I would like to use more images to explain a concept instead of just text.

[image]

---

[image]

among others...

any idea? or only it is possible if I do this in a picture?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's certainly _possible_ but I'm not sure if it would be easy. You could use the `grid` package to place lines, squares, circles, arrows and text in a drawing, but this would involve working out programatically where you want each element to be. If you are just looking for package recommendations, I'm afraid that is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You are more likely to get help if you edit your question to ask how you could reproduce a particular figure in R, but even then, you should show how you have attempted this on your own.

Comment: This plot is something you'd normally construct with a flowcharting program. There are many good pay options. Then there is draw.io available free online which is good. For simple jobs, dia at http://dia-installer.de/ can serve. It is free and open source. Any good drawing program can be made to serve, but they aren't optimised for this sort of output, really. Mindmanager has an option for your second type of layout if you happen to have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try package **DiagrammeR**:

```
library("DiagrammeR")

create_graph() %>%
  add_cycle(n = 5, label=letters[1:5]) %>%
  render_graph()
```

see also: https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphviz_and_mermaid.html

Comment: Could you tell me if is there any way to resize the circles? @tpetzoldt

Answer (score 1):

The style of nodes and edges can be configured:

```
library("DiagrammeR")

create_graph() %>%
  add_cycle(n = 5, label = letters[1:5], 
            node_aes = node_aes(color = "red", width = 1)) %>%
  render_graph()
```